# Why scala compiler doesn't infer the evidence parameter type?

Tags: scala

Type constraints are implemented as the following types:

```
  abstract class <:<[-From, +To] extends Function1[From, To]
  object <:< {
    implicit def conforms[A] = new (A <:< A) { def apply(x: A) = x }
  }
```

we use the evidence in our code like this:

```
def firstLast[A, C](it: C)(implicit ev: C <:< Iterable[A]) =
(it.head, it.last)
```

when i clear the `apply` method compiler says that `it` does not contain `head` and `last` while the implicit type resolution already was successful. This means that C is subtype of Iterable[A]. But the compiler can't infer that. Is this just that Scala's type inference is not powerful enough?

Comment: What code is producing the error you are describing? At first blush, this appears to work as intended.

Comment: `<:<` is a default operator available in Scala, why are you going custom btw>

Comment: Don't tell me you are talking about errors given by some IDE like eclipse or intellij and not Scala compiler itself ?

Comment: I mean when `ev` is resolved as evidence it conforms that `C` is subtype of `Iterable[A]` so we would not need define `apply` method to be called impilicitly to infer that `C` is subtype of `Iterable[A]` in `(it.head, it.last)`. I think scala type inference doesn't memorize evidence in the subsequent inferences.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand... what do you find wrong with this. It is working fine,

```
scala> :pa
// Entering paste mode (ctrl-D to finish)

def firstLast[A, C](it: C)(implicit ev: C <:< Iterable[A]) = (it.head, it.last)

// Exiting paste mode, now interpreting.

firstLast: [A, C](it: C)(implicit ev: <:<[C,Iterable[A]])(A, A)

scala> firstLast(List(1,2,3))
res0: (Int, Int) = (1,3)
```